# Visual Studio Smart Tabs for JavaScript -- not available?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Last week I tried out a visual studio extension called VSVim.  After a few days I decided to uninstall it.

All of my Javascript auto-formatting is now broken.  The first thing I noticed is that "Smart" indenting is not available when I go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->JScript.

Previously, if I completed a statement with a ";" VS would kindly reformat my code.  Now it does nothing :(

It is getting very annoying; I was spoiled by the ease of use.

Any thoughts?

[image: Why no work?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is disabled by default.  It is grayed out on my machine also.